# how to get text from twitch redeem points using selenium (python)?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get text from "Redeemed Highlight My Message" twitch chat, here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Project\Project\Rebot Router\chromedriver11.exe')
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/nightblue3")

while True:
    text11= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="6583f0b7722e3be4537e78903686d3b4"]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[116]/div[2]/span[4]/span')
    text44= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("chat-line--inline chat-line__message")
    print(str(text11))
    print(str(text44))
```

but when i run it that's what i get

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

and when i use .text like that

```
while True:
    text11= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="6583f0b7722e3be4537e78903686d3b4"]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[116]/div[2]/span[4]/span').text
    text44= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("chat-line--inline chat-line__message").text

    print(str(text11))
    print(str(text44))
```

that's what i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Project/Project/Rebot Router/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    text11= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="6583f0b7722e3be4537e78903686d3b4"]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[116]/div[2]/span[4]/span').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

so any help please.
btw text11 and text44 is the same i just use in text11 xpath and text44 class_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    Texts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='text-fragment']")
    for x in range (0, len(Texts)):
        print(Texts[x].text)
```